# Which String Converter and When And Why?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know the title might look little vague but I couldn't come up with something better. So my question is that in my company they are paying close attention to String conversion functions.
And so far I've been dealing with `CStr()`, `Convert.ToString()` and `ToString()` and I need to understand what the difference is between these functions.

They said they were preferring the `CStr()` and `Convert.ToString()` and I would like to know why they decided to go with these two?

Is it because `ToString()` depends on the object?

Comment: "Is it because `ToString()` depends on the object?" Yup. You can't invoke `Nothing.ToString()` because there's literally nothing to invoke it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because of the failure differences, CStr and Convert.ToString() don't throw an exception and return a default known value; .ToString() can throw an exception.

Theoretically, either way is ok; you can catch an exception around .ToString() and it's not a performance overhead because exception handling only incurs a cost if it's used.

But to developers from a VB/ASP background the known default failure path is more familiar and comfortable.

Nowadays, it's a style choice really.

Edit: In other words, .ToString does depend on the object, if the object is null then it has to throw an exception. Convert.ToString() would test the object to make sure it's not null and can behave differently.

Comment: From a personal perspective, I come from an ASM/C/C++ background, in my heart, I prefer .ToString() and testing if the object isn't null; not really sure why that's different, but it feels like it's fewer steps of processing :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of code that demonstrates string conversions with each method on three types of data: string, numeric and null reference. Note that only the instance.ToString call will throw an exception if the object has not been initialized.

```
imports System

public module MyModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim nothingObj as Object ' leave uninitialized on purpose

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("hello Convert.ToString"))
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(22))
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(nothingObj))

        Console.WriteLine(CStr("hello CStr"))
        Console.WriteLine(CStr(23))
        Console.WriteLine(CStr(nothingObj))

        Console.WriteLine("hello .ToString".ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(24.ToString())
        try
            Console.WriteLine(nothingObj.ToString())
        catch
            Console.WriteLine(CStr("tried ToString on null!"))
        end try

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
end module
```

Output:

```
hello Convert.ToString
22

hello CStr
23

hello .ToString
24
tried ToString on null!
```

I put this little demo together in Snippet Compiler. If you don't have it yet, [get it](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/). It's perfect for tweaking with little concepts like this.

Comment: That looks awesome. Thanks for the code snippet. Definitely worked out in my side.